# Vim: Simple "jump to file" command?

Tags: vim

What's the simplest way to "jump to a file somewhere in my source tree by name"? For example, if I'm working with "libfoo" that contains `libfoo/foo/foo.py`, I'd like to be able to jump to `foo.py` from anywhere within `libfoo/**`[0].

Possibly some way to do this with a tags file?

[0]: that is, `libfoo/` and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check out [command-t](https://wincent.com/products/command-t/), [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984), or [FuzzyFinder_Textmate](http://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate)

Personally, I find command-t has the best UI, but FuF_Textmate is best for quickly getting to the right place in very large projects (which is why I use it after trying all 3)

Note that fuzzyfinder_textmate is unmaintained by its origional author, so you may have to poke around the gh network tab to find who has the most up to date branch. also note it is a bit of a pain to install.

Comment: I use FuzzyFinder_Textmate already for its tag jumping… But it's a bit annoying to use `file` because, if I'm in `libfoo/bar/baz/`, then I've got to type `\f../../../**/foo.py`.

Comment: Possibly there is some way to set it up so that it will default to using some directory as the root?

Comment: as far as i know, fuzzyfinder_textmate only does file names, and will always start in the place that you opened vim (which can actually be a pain sometimes). maybe you are using fuzzyfinder?

Comment: Err, yea — maybe I am just using FuzzyFinder.

Comment: the main difference between the two is for fuf, you have to walk through the whole path (i.e. l/f/fpy) with fuf_tm, it will just match by file name instead of complete path until you start using /s. so fpy will match it, but if that is too general you could do foo/fpy to narrow your search down

Comment: [CtrlP](http://kien.github.com/ctrlp.vim/) is another one for the list. Similar to the others in this answer, but pure vimscript.

Answer (score 19):

Add `**` is to you comma-separated vim `path` variable (not system path) and if you're in some parent dir of the project use:

```
:find foo.py
```

Comment: voted you up cause find is definitely simpler then installing and configuring a plugin.

Comment: Hrm, that doesn't seem to do what I want… If my CWD is `libfoo/`, `find foo.py` doesn't work. Possibly `:find` isn't recursive?

Comment: What does :set path tell you?  Mine is `path=.,**,,`, which I think is the default.  It definitely recurses for me.  :find password in / find /etc/passwd.

Comment: Indeed, looks like `set path=.,**,,` is in my ~/.vimrc, which I cribbed from somewhere 10 years ago.  Add that and `:find` is recursive.

Comment: Ah, there's the problem: my `path` is missing `**`. Strange, though — I'm running a mostly stock 7.2, and if `**` is default, then I don't know why I wouldn't have it (mine is `.,/usr/include,,`).

Comment: Default *is* `".,/usr/include,,"` on unix, as stated on `:help path`

Comment: I guess that's the trouble with bringing the same ,vimrc along for years -- you forget the defaults.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vim's tab completion of filenames in conjuction with the `**` recursive directory expansion.

e.g. type:  `:e libfoo/**/foo.py` and hit TAB.  This will search down from the libfoo directory to find a file that matches.  If there is more than one match you can cycle through them with  the TAB key.  When you find the one you want press enter to complete the command and edit the file.

For more about the ** matching do `:h starstar`.   It requires a version of Vim compiled with the +path_extra option.

If you have already edited the file once you can also search the buffers for partial name matches with the `:b name` command.  e.g.   `:b foo.py<TAB>` will expand to a buffer name that has 'foo.py' anywhere in it.    N.B. it matches the entire path, so `:b foo<TAB>` would match all buffers with files from the libfoo directory.

Comment: upvoted because it is simple, as requested in the question, and just uses built-in vim functionality

Answer (score 1):

**`ctags --extra=f .`** creates tags with the same name as files pointing to the first line:

```
ctags -R --extra=f .
```

Then you can just do:

```
:tag file_na
```

and tab complete away.

Mentioned at: [Vim and ctags: tag filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347982/vim-and-ctags-tag-filenames)

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

https://github.com/zhchang/quick_file

unique features:
1. you don't need to know where exactly it is, as long as it is in one of the sub dirs
2. you don't have to remember the full name, fragments will do
3. it will go to most shallow match, but with more fragments of the path supplied, it will match deeper.

Answer (score 0):

## ctrlp.vim

Full path fuzzy **file**, **buffer**, **mru**, **tag**, **...** finder for Vim.

- Written in pure Vimscript for MacVim, gVim and Vim 7.0+.
- Full support for Vim's regexp as search patterns.
- Built-in Most Recently Used (MRU) files monitoring.
- Built-in project's root finder.
- Open multiple files at once.
- Create new files and directories.
- Extensible.

You can find it at https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim.

Answer (score -1):

```
map <S-F12> :execute "!start explorer \"" . expand( "%:p:h" ) . "\""<CR>
```

starts up an explorer window in the directory of the file you are using

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I see how that's relevant to the question…