# Vim and ctags: tag filenames

Tags: vim, ctags

Is it possible to have ctags generate tags for filenames as well? I would like to be able to jump to a file given a filename. :find seems to be awfully slow compare to tags...

Answer (score 15):

Try running `ctags -R --extra=f .`

The `--extra=f` option tells ctags to:

> "Include an entry for the base file name of every source file (e.g. "example.c"), which addresses the first line of the file."

When you open vim, you can the use `:tag <filename>` to jump to the first line of the file.

Comment: using `extra=+f` AND `--langmap=FILE:.html.twig.xml.yml` you can have easilly access to any type of file: https://github.com/docteurklein/dot-files/blob/master/ctags#L23
`

Answer (score 6):

You can open the filename under the cursor with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor

Comment: I tried to set path to <mycode>\** then use gf... it is almost as slow as find.

Comment: It's worth noting that `gf` only works for files in the current path. If your tag file contains information about shared libraries (i.e. stdio.h), you will want to use [Tim Henigan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6349262/1011470).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `cscope`:

```
:cs find f <filename>
```

or, if you've setup cscope in vim as recommended in `:help cscope`, put the cursor on top of a filename, and press `<C-_>f`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting your path and then using vim's 'gf' command?

Comment: I tried to set path to <mycode>\** then use gf... it is almost as slow as find.